# What type of birds can live in my systems of caves?

Tags: magic, caves

The story I am trying to write happens underground in system of caverns that originate from either underground rivers or a massive roots system that have begun to rot. Creating mostly long spherical hallway up to 30 meters wide and tall with an average around 10 meters

Some of those caverns have abundant plant and animal life.

The light came from crystal and the aeration just work (I have nothing right now but it's not a concern for the question)

My hypothesis is that birds like those that live in forest in the three should be able to live in such a system the same way that the land animal does but I am unsure of it or if some species would be better for it than other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cave Swiftlets**

[image]

These guys nest in caves and make their nests glued to the rock face by gumming together vegetation with their saliva.
The nests are a delicacy and are harvested by cave acrobats.

[image]

The swiftlets don't mind the dark. They have relatives -- other swifts and swallows --  that also make their nests glued to sheer surfaces. The common swallow:

[image]

On the other hand, these guys do not hunt in the caves. They nest in caves BECAUSE the caves are devoid of other life. So they are safe from predators. If the cave has loads of animals it is no longer a safe nest site.

Perhaps the birds nest in some of the less accessible cracks of the caves. For example there used to be a long, thin and twisting tree root that decayed. The birds nest in the tunnel left behind.

Answer (score 3):

Flying is energetically expensive. It makes sense to keep it as a feature in a body plan if the cost is justified by some benefit.

For rather constrained environments like the one you describe, I suspect that, though a bird would be able to live in, it would slowly adapt to be more of a climber/glider than a proper flying creature: similar result with less expenditure.

Comment: If the birds have no predators & food is easily obtained, some may eventually lose the ability to fly.

Comment: would a climber/glider be  able to hunt flying insect correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

**Kakapos**

[image: kakapo]

[source](https://phys.org/news/2008-10-quest-kakapo-fragrance-spans-centuries.html)

These are really big flightless parrots.  They can walk.  They can climb.   They are strong and they can pull vegetation off the cave walls.  Their big bodies let them store away calories against the lean times.  Their size makes them impervious to most of the small predators in the tunnel system.